# kendo ui datasource mapping of the model fails

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

we would like to migrate our grid to Kendo UI grid and if it fits for us we will buy it.
I tried to implement it, but I'm blocked with an issue. The id column works only if I provide 'id' instead of '_id' in the json 
and all the json property have to be the same as the model and column fild name.

For example if You change the 'title' filed to 'title2' and do the same in the column settings, the grid fails, there are empty columns.
Or if I change the '_id' to 'id' the id column will contanins the values.

So for me it seems the mapping of the model fails, the 'from' doesn't work properly.

Check the example in jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/welone/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test youre example and for me its really looks like bug with `from` and underscore prefix variables.

As workaround just use `field name` (which is also path to value in ds) instead `from` field.

[here some edits in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/huvivipani/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, we will report it, when we have purchased.